# Two Databases in Eloquent ORM without Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, psql

i use Eloquent ORM without Laravel, it works OK with one database, but i don't know how use a second database.. i use Capsule to configure eloquent

DATABASE.PHP FILE:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';  

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;  

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection(
    array(
     'driver'    => 'pgsql',
     'host'      => 'localhost',
     'database'  => 'database01',
     'username'  => 'postgres',
     'password'  => 'password',
     'charset'   => 'utf8',
     'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
     'prefix'    => ''
    )
);



$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

how can i add a second database?
(i see a different configuration of database.php file that starts with a "return array(..." but i don't know how use that for Capsule or other way)

thanks!

Comment: Did you try to call `addConnection` again, with the other database's info?

Comment: yes i try, but doesn't work, error with the firt connection

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and it took me a while to find the answer in another forum.

this is what I ended up doing

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

//connection to first database

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => $app->config->get('db.driver'),
    'host' => $app->config->get('db.host'),
    'database' => $app->config->get('db.name'),
    'username' => $app->config->get('db.username'),
    'password' => $app->config->get('db.password'),
    'charset' => $app->config->get('db.charset'),
    'collation' => $app->config->get('db.collation'),
    'prefix' => $app->config->get('db.prefix'),
], 'default'); //the important line


// connection to second database

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => $app->config->get('db2.driver'),
    'host' => $app->config->get('db2.host'),
    'database' => $app->config->get('db2.name'),
    'username' => $app->config->get('db2.username'),
    'password' => $app->config->get('db2.password'),
    'charset' => $app->config->get('db2.charset'),
    'collation' => $app->config->get('db2.collation'),
    'prefix' => $app->config->get('db2.prefix'),
], 'secondary_db');  // the important line

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Don't think too much about this kind of syntax: $app->config->get('db2.driver'). I'm just calling my parameters from another file, that's all.

What you should do is see **"the important line"** to which I added a comment

then, you can go ahead and use this on your secondary models to let Eloquent know that you actually want to use the secondary database

```
class Domains extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'secondary_db';
    .
 .
.
```

you don't need to specify the connection variable in the models using the default database.